# Android studio when try to build apk Error: "Expecting a file or a directory"

Tags: android, android-studio

So i get this Error when i try to build an Apk in Android Studio: "Expecting a file or a directory: D:\Android\game - Android Studio\core\Users\ManuGil\Documents\LibGDX\Juegos 15-20\360\game\libs\tween-engine-api.jar". So and when it has showed me expecting a file ore Directory i thought i am going to look for this file but in my explorer i just can find the files until "core" cause in the Folder core there's no folder "Users".
[The picture shows the error in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivQND.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Please click File-->Project Structrue ... --> SDK Location -->JDK location**

Then, type this in the box !!

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152

'jdk1.8.0_152' could be different depending on the version of jdk.

i hope this works for someone who suffers from the error